# Insert XAML into another XAML MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm building a MAUI app, the main page is stored in a file called MainPage.xaml. I also created a popup with the  [CommunityToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Maui/2.0.0#dependencies-body-tab) package. I was wondering if there is a way to include this PopUpPage inside my MainPage when a button is clicked. the PopupPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Myproject.PopupPage"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

I tried with this xaml code but it didn't compile

```
<toolkit:Popup x:Name="MyPopup" IsVisible="{Binding IsPickerVisible}">
            <local:PopupPage />    
</toolkit:Popup>
```

Answer (score 1):

There definitely it a way to do that! But in your code something doesn't look right, preventing this to work. Let's take a step back and see what you are trying to do.

In the `PopupPage`, you are defining a `toolkit:Popup` so a complete popup, that is needed to actually show the popup in your application. So far, so good.

However, in your second snippet you're now trying to wrap the `PopupPage` in another popup. That is not supported.

I don't have all the details on what you are trying to do, but assuming that you want to reuse this part underneath in both of these places:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label 
        Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

What you want to do, is put only this piece in a separate XAML file. Let's say that we name this `PopupContent.xaml`. As a template you might want to choose the `ContentView (XAML)` although it doesn't really matter as long as it's a XAML file. Make sure the content looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VerticalStackLayout xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Myproject.PopupContent">
    <Label 
        Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Don't forget to update the base class in the code-behind (pro-tip: you can even remove the inheritance there altogether as that is already inferred from the XAML).

Now update your XAML snippets from your questions like this:

```xml
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Myproject.PopupPage"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Myproject">
    <local:PopupContent />
</toolkit:Popup>
```

Note how I added the `xmlns:local` in the root, make sure that it reflects the namespace of your app, and then you add the `<local:PopupContent />` as a component, if you will.

Now do the same for your second XAML snippet and you can share it between both!

Comment: The last code you provided is supposed to be in my MainPage.xaml? Also I want the popup visibility to be binded to a variable where should i place the visibility tag?

Comment: Where you want to put it or how to arrange it is up to you. I don't know your project or what you are trying to do!